# Why my form won't submit correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have User model and Comment model using **acts_as_commentable_with_threading**
I'm trying to put the comment function on each User's show page with partial.
But When I try to submit a form, it shows routing error.
Why is this?

**Error**

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/user/john/add_comment"
```

**models/user.rb**

```
acts_as_commentable
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'comment', :user => @user %>
```

**views/users/_comment.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Posted by</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

<% @user.comment_threads.each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.id %></td>
    <td><%= comment.title %></td>
    <td><%= comment.body %></td>
    <td><%= comment.subject %></td>
    <td><%= comment.user.user_profile.nickname if comment.user.user_profile %></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'destroy', comment, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :disable_with => 'deleting...', method: :delete %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>


<%= form_for @user, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div> 

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "user/:id/add_comment" => 'users#add_comment', :as => :add_comment_user
get "user/:id/delete_comment" => 'users#delete_comment', :as => :delete_comment_user
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def add_comment
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @user_who_commented = current_user
    @comment = Comment.build_from( @user, @user_who_commented.id, params[:users][:body] )
    @comment.save
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => params[:users][:id]
    flash[:notice] = "comment added!"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your route is for a GET, and the form is a POST.

Comment: I changed my routes to like this get **"user/:id/add_comment" => 'users#add_comment', :as => :add_comment_user, :via => :post** but it still says the same error:(

Comment: @HUSTEN Why would you keep using "get"?

Comment: where at? I'm trying to use post

Comment: @HUSTEN ... Where you say "get". As in `get "user/:id etc"`.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a post route. Also you are posting to user/:name/add_comment, you should post the the user id. You can use the name but this would need to be unique across all users.

This line is also wrong.

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

You can either pass in the `params[:username]` of `find_by_id`

Comment: Sorry about that I use to_param as slug that's why